# How to automaticaly get the itemExtent in SliverFixedExtentList?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to use a `SliverFixedExtentList`, but I don't want to hard-code the `itemExtent` parameter, instead I would like to programatically get the final rendered height of my `Widget` and pass this to `itemExtent`, this way, if I modify it in the future, the `itemExtent` will adapt to it automatically. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

In those cases, we should use the [`SliverPrototypeExtentList`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverPrototypeExtentList/prototypeItem.html) instead.